# Mapping Multiple Textures to a Cube's faces in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have just began opengl programming in android and i am fairly new to opengl as well. I've been using nehe's opengl tutorials as well as insanitydesign's android ports. I successfully managed to create a cube with a single texture mapped to all its 6 faces. I even mapped multiple textures to different faces of the cube.
        But the way I did it was to create 6 faces seperately, have 6 seperate index and texture buffers and then using glBindTexture() with the selected texture for each face and then calling glDrawElements. Isn't there an efficient way around this. Should i use a cube map texture instead of a GL_TEXTURE_2D?

Any suggestions would be appreciated?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very efficient way is using a texture atlas, and adjusting texture coordinates of each cube face to match coordinates in the atlas.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to create a texture atlas via code or should it be done normally in photoshop?

Comment: does not exist's a easy way to load different textures on each side of a cube?